# .NET 3.5 (C#) application does not run on Windows XP Professional

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

I have a .NET 3.5 (C#) application, but interestingly it does not run on Windows XP. I have checked .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1 are installed. When I run the application, no error message pops up. It just does not run. What could I try out?

Comment: Have you checked the Application Event Log?

Comment: Could you paste your code if it is short or Main method?

Comment: Try to run it from command line. It might display some errors on the console.

Comment: if the application Event log wont show you anything you can remote debug

Comment: what kind of project do you want to run in window xp?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Application Event Log says ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting." It doesn't help me that much though.

Answer (score 1):

this is may be because you have build this application on 64 bit machine  please try to compile it over 32  bit machine and re run

Answer (score 1):

You could install [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) (it has the advantage of being quite light, not too invasive, not like a full Visual Studio install), and run your .EXE from its console. WinDbg will break on the first exception. You will be then able to dig out further using something like [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) (WinDbg extension for managed .NET programs).

Answer (score 1):

If your application requires the full ".Net Framework 3.5" make sure so it isn't the ".Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile" that is installed.

*This have fooled me more than once...*

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have "appname.exe.config" file next to your app, or, in some cases, it have helped moving app in different drive/folder.

Folder path containing some language specific symbols might allso cause some compatability issues or runtime errors on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied all necessary DLL files with the EXE file? Except those already included in the .NET framework, of course.
If so, you should check the event log to see If you can find any hints.  You can also use the PDB files in a test period bexcause this will provide more info to the exception and event log.